# Matlab Time Series (AR, MA, ARIMA)

Tags: statistics, matlab, regression

Is there a function which calculates an AR(p), MA(q), ARIMA(p,q) process in MATLAB which is free. I know of Econometrics toolbox, but I have to pay for that. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: Use R? It is free and well equipped for the task.

Comment: I have used R, but I was wondering if there was a way to implement this in Matlab. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Judging from this file exchange submission, it is possible.

Though the regular method recommends you to use the Econometrics toolbox, this allows you to do it with just the statistics toolbox.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25611-arfima-simulations/content/ARFIMA_SIM.m

Comment: Thank you, not sure if I want to go through to double check